# Leading zero are not displaying in export to excel

Tags: asp.net

While exporting the data to the excel leading zeros are not displaying in export to excel.What is the solution for this.

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in grd.Rows)
    {
        GridView gvOrderscell = (row.FindControl("gv_Child") as GridView);
        foreach (GridViewRow crow in gvOrderscell.Rows)
        {
            GridView gvOrderQty = (crow.FindControl("gv_ChildQty") as GridView);
            foreach (GridViewRow qtyrow in gvOrderQty.Rows)
            {
                Response.Write(row.Cells[1].Text + "\t" + row.Cells[2].Text + "\t" + row.Cells[3].Text);
                Response.Write("\t" + crow.Cells[1].Text + "\t" + crow.Cells[2].Text + "\t" + crow.Cells[3].Text + "\t" + crow.Cells[4].Text + "\t" + crow.Cells[5].Text);
                Response.Write("\t" + qtyrow.Cells[0].Text + "\t" + qtyrow.Cells[1].Text);
                Response.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Refer this: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-WordExcelPDFCSV-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that Excel does. It interprets the value as a number and automatically removed leading zeros for you. If you put a single quote ' in front of the value, Excel will interpret it as a string and keep the leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a character <kbd>`</kbd> before your string it will work. Excel consider it as a number and remove the leading zeros.

```
Response.Write("`"+row.Cells[1].Text + "\t" + "`"+row.Cells[2].Text + "\t" +"`"+ row.Cells[3].Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse data with *formatting*.

Excel will suppress leading zeros since they are not needed to represent a number.

You can retain a *string* type by prefixing a single quotation character, but then it's harder (and slower) to use that that cell in a numeric calculation.

If you right click on a cell in Excel, choose Formatting, select Custom, then enter say 00000 as your format, then Excel will *format* the numerical value to always have 5 digits, with any necessary leading zeros supplied. Adjust that format to suit your particular need.